# Where to specify Spark configs when running Spark app in EMR cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, emr

When I am running Spark app on EMR, what is the difference between adding configs to spark/conf spark-defaults.conf file VS adding them when running spark submit?

For example, If I adding this to my conf spark-defaults.conf :

```
spark.master         yarn
spark.executor.instances            4
spark.executor.memory               29G
spark.executor.cores                3
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead  4096
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead    2048
spark.driver.memory                 12G
spark.driver.cores                  1
spark.default.parallelism           48
```

Is that the same as adding it to command line arguments :

> Arguments :/home/hadoop/spark/bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster
>   --master yarn-cluster --conf spark.driver.memory=12G --conf spark.executor.memory=29G --conf spark.executor.cores=3 --conf
>   spark.executor.instances=4 --conf
>   spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096 --conf
>   spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=2048 --conf spark.driver.cores=1
>   --conf spark.default.parallelism=48 --class com.emr.spark.MyApp s3n://mybucket/application/spark/MeSparkApplication.jar

?

And would it be the same if I add this in my Java Code, for example:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(applicationName);
        sparkConf.set("spark.executor.instances", "4");
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in priority. According to [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties):

> Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then
>   flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the
>   spark-defaults.conf file